# Generics in C# binary operator overloading

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Consider two generic classes

```
class Result<T1, T2> {}
class Value<T> {}
```

Is there some way of overloading the `+` operator that would allow me to write the following in such a way that the types are properly captured in the result, i.e. `r` has the type `Result<int,string>`?

```
Value<int> a;
Value<string> b;
var r = a + b;
```

I can write this:

```
class Value<T> {
   public static Result<T,T> operator+(Value<T> a, Value<T> b) { ... }
}
```

Which will work for any pair of `Value<T>`'s, such as two `Value<int>`'s, but what about when the types differ?

Looking at previous questions about C# operator overloading, none of them seem to answer this specific question. This one is perhaps the closest: [Overloading operator for generics C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158535/overloading-operator-for-generics-c-sharp)

The motivation behind trying to do this is that if the `Result<T1, T2>` class has a method that takes a delegate as an argument, knowing the specific types `T1` and `T2` at compile time makes it possible to omit types from the lambda expression when calling that method.

Comment: So you want an operator `+` to be defined for `Value<T>` and `Value<U>` for any two types `T` and `U`?

Comment: @Sweeper That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the operator `+` to be defined on any two `Value<T>` and `Value<U>`, where `T` and `U` are any types, the operator needs to be generic. Using some made-up syntax, it would look something like:

```
class Value<T> {
    public static Result<T,U> operator+<U>(Value<T> a, Value<U> b) { 
        // create a Result<T, U>
    }
}
```

However, the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#operators) of user-defined operators is very strict, and is nowhere like that of method declarations:

```
operator_declaration
    : attributes? operator_modifier+ operator_declarator operator_body
    ;
operator_declarator
    : unary_operator_declarator
    | binary_operator_declarator
    | conversion_operator_declarator
    ;
binary_operator_declarator
    : type 'operator' overloadable_binary_operator '(' type identifier ',' type identifier ')'
    ;

overloadable_binary_operator
    : '+'   | '-'   | '*'   | '/'   | '%'   | '&'   | '|'   | '^'   | '<<'
    | right_shift | '=='  | '!='  | '>'   | '<'   | '>='  | '<='
    ;
operator_body
    : block
    | '=>' expression ';'
    | ';'
    ;
```

Though they may look a lot like method declarations, their syntax is specified in a very different way, and do not allow generic parameters.

Furthermore, using this hypothetical generic operator would require [type inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#type-inference), which is applied when [invoking a method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#method-invocations). This does not happen during operator resolution.

As a workaround, you can declare a `Plus` method:

```
class Value<T> {
    public Result<T,U> Plus<U>(Value<U> other) { 
        // create a Result<T, U>
    }
}

// You'd be doing a.Plus(b), rather than "a + b"
// You still get the type inference you wanted
```

Comment: I suspected that was the case. It's a bit disappointing, because there doesn't seem to be any reason why generics in operator overloading should be disallowed like this.